# Easily embedding (some aspect of) a Dropbox file's metadata in a webpage?

Tags: metadata, jekyll, dropbox

I provide a link on my Jekyll site to my Curriculum Vitae, which I have saved as a Word document on my computer. When I edit it, I update it on the web by saving it to Dropbox as a PDF, which I link to on a dedicated page of my site. Users click the link and can view the file on Dropbox's interface. It's not super elegant, but it's working for now.

I would like to have the file's date last modified appear on that webpage. Right now, I've been editing this date manually whenever I update the document, which sort of defeats the purpose of the easy "save to Dropbox" workflow.

Is there a relatively simple way to query the date modified and display it in text? I'm thinking I probably have to call the Dropbox API, since that's what I would do if performing the data analysis I'm currently comfortable with locally. JSON, however, is not my native language, and I want to ensure that I'm not barking up the wrong tree before I invest a ton of time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API does offer the ability to retrieve file metadata, such as the file modified time. To do so, you should use [the Dropbox API v2 /files/get_metadata endpoint](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#response-handling-edge-cases).

We recommend using [an official SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation), if one is available for your platform. There will be a corresponding method in it for that endpoint.